# Clang-Tidy warning when using typedef enums

Tags: c++, clang, clang-tidy

I am looking over some older code someone else wrote and the person is often using this type of code:

```cpp
typedef enum {
  id1=1
  id2=11
  id3=2
  id4=3
} enumName_e
```

This type is then used in functions all over the place. While this works clang-tidy is complaining that `using` should be used instead of `typedef` which in this case won't work easily. Is this bad code that should be changed or is clang-tidy wrong here?

Comment: clang-tidy is getting confused because you're running C++ checks on C code.

Comment: Ok that makes sense thank you. Interestingly enough most of the code is C++ and this was all in .h files which are commonly used in C++ so I kinda assumed this was C++ as well

Comment: After further inspection that code is definitely used for C++ compilation exclusively. Is it still fine to have it this way?